# Chrome Identity API - POST request

Tags: google-chrome, post, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-chrome-app

I am trying to develop a chrome extension in which I need to use 3rd party Oauth2 authentication. The third party service I want to use, only supports POST requests. But it seems that the launchWebAuthFlow method in the Chrome Identity API, only supports sending GET requests, as all the query parameters are sent in the URL itself. Is this correct? If yes, how should I do authentication?

UPDATE : The API I want to connect is that of [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially you're right about POST requirements. But it is only used to initialize Oauth flow.
According to the documentation:

1) You must make a POST request to obtain a request token from Pocket auth service

2) Redirect user to the auth page: https://getpocket.com/auth/authorize?request_token=YOUR_REQUEST_TOKEN&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI

Which means that you have to make a simple XHR to retrieve request token and then you can use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow function to begin Oauth flow.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try launchWebAuthFlow? You may find that it works. Once authenticated, you can exercise the API via POST, using XMLHttpRequest. (launchWebAuthFlow only handles the authentication, not the API itself.)

Comment: It isn't working. I need to send a POST request to get the access-token.

Comment: And you're sure the site is using OAuth2 and not OAuth1? I have used launchWebAuthFlow with an OAuth1 site, and it required some XMLHttpRequest interaction in addition to the OAuth part that launchWebAuthFlow needed. I'm also wondering if the OAuth2 (if it is OAuth2) that the site is using is non-standard. Anyway, sorry I can't help, but if you figure this out, please post further results here.